# Vagrant syntax error

Tags: vagrant

I have this block of code here:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config| 
    config.vm.define “web” do |web| 
        web.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"                          web.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080           web.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|                            puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"                         puppet.manifest_file = "site.pp" 
        end 
    end 
    config.vm.define “db” do |db|  
        db.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64" 
        db.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8081            db.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet| 
            puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"                         puppet.manifest_file = "myweb.pp"  
            #remember you can use shell instead of puppet! 
        end 
    end 
end
```

When I try to do vagrant up, I get the errors:

```
1. Vagrantfile:2: invalid multibyte char (UTF-8)
2. Vagrantfile:2: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end config.vm.define �web� do |web|
```

I'm pretty sure my code is correct, but why is it complaining?

Answer (score 0):

You have smart quotes (curly quotes) instead of regular quotes around `web` and `db`. These quotes are UTF-8 characters, as opposed to regular ASCII (and apparently even use multiple bytes per character).

Use this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config| 
    config.vm.define "web" do |web| 
        web.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
        web.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
        web.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
            puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
            puppet.manifest_file = "site.pp" 
        end 
    end

    config.vm.define "db" do |db|  
        db.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64" 
        db.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8081
        db.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet| 
            puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
            puppet.manifest_file = "myweb.pp"  
            #remember you can use shell instead of puppet! 
        end 
    end 
end
```

How are you editing files, by the way? It’s not common for code editors to use smart quotes. But if you’re using a regular text editor (like TextEdit on a Mac), it would probably autocorrect your quotes into these.